# Using ViewPager with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list of images that I display in a `ImageListFragment` fragment of my MainActivity, clicking on one of those images should open that image as `ImageDisplayFragment` inside `FooPager`. I have created a `FooPager` activity so that when the image the user clicked in ImageListFragment is displayed, the user can then swipe and view all images. The problem I have is that when I click on the image I want to view in `ImageListFragment`, it displays the very first image in my `/drawable` directory instead of the actual image I click on. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is `ImageListFragment`:

```
public class ImageListFragment extends Fragment {
     private int[] mImageResIds;
     private OnGalleryImageSelected mListener;
     public static ImageListFragment newInstance() {
     return new ImageListFragment();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mListener = (OnGalleryImageSelected) context;

    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final TypedArray typedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
    final int imageCount = 18;
    mImageResIds = new int[imageCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
        mImageResIds[i] = typedArray.getResourceId(i, 0);
    }
    typedArray.recycle();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_list, container, false);

    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(activity));
    return view;
}

class GalleryImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(mLayoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final int imageResId = mImageResIds[position];

        viewHolder.setData(imageResId);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(imageResId);
                Intent intent = FooPager.newIntent(getActivity(),imageResId);
                startActivity (intent);
               // mListener.OnGalleryImageSelected(imageResId);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageResIds.length;
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_image);

    }
    private void setData(int imageResId) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
    }
}
public interface OnGalleryImageSelected {
    void OnGalleryImageSelected(int imageResId);
}
}
```

This is what my pager activity looks like:

```
 public class FooPager extends FragmentActivity{
  public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_ID = "meow";
  private ViewPager mViewPager;
  private Integer images [] = {
        R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,
        R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,R.drawable.i,R.drawable.j,
        R.drawable.k, R.drawable.l, R.drawable.m,R.drawable.n,R.drawable.o,
        R.drawable.p, R.drawable.q, R.drawable.r
};

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext,FooPager.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID,id);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_pager);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.activity_image_pager_view_pager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager ();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println(images[position]);
            int id = images[position];
            return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }
    });

    for (int i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

And then `ImageDetailFragment`fragment:

```
 public class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
   private static final String IMAGE_ID = "imageResId";

   public static ImageDetailFragment newInstance(int imageResId) {

    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(IMAGE_ID, imageResId);
    final ImageDetailFragment fragment = new ImageDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_details, container, false);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_image);
    final Bundle args = getArguments();
    imageView.setImageResource(args.getInt(IMAGE_ID));
    return view;
}

}
```

How do I fix my `FooPager` activity so that it actually displays the image I clicked on from within `ImageListFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

> it displays the very first image in my /drawable directory instead of
>   the actual image I click on

In your `FooPager` Activity, this will show the first item in your viewpager. That the reason why it display the first item (i = 0 and break)

```
for (int i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
    }
```

YOu need to send the `position` from `ImageListFragment` to `FooPager`, not `imageResId` and set `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)`. If you send `imageResId`, you need to browse in you list images

```
for (int i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
               if(images[i] == imageResId) {
                   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                   break;
               }
        }
```

Comment: I tried commenting out that entire loop and I still get the same behavior. This makes me think maybe the bug is in the getItem method inside FooPager.

Comment: Did you find out your problem?

Comment: No, not yet. I changed around by code a bit, but now in my slide scroll in FooPager, it just shows the same image over and over through the scroll. http://pastebin.com/dkq3DFB4. In FooPager I get the position in onCreate, and try to use that position inside getItem (instead of the position passed in getItem as an argument. Hence, the repeated images when I swipe. Pretty new to android so I have no idea how to fix this.